# implementing addtag in drupal template

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

i have code in my template:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'article')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('field_show_on', 'tid', $group['identifier'], '=') // taxonomy identifier
    ->fieldCondition('field_perks_categories', 'tid', $categories['tid'], '=')
    ->fieldCondition('field_perks_sub_categories', 'tid', $subcategory['tid'], '=')
    ->execute();
```

i have other table named "artc_order" which contents nid, weight to to order article manually 
i want to implement this:
http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/05/16/drupal-7-order-entityfieldquery-by-random-using-hook_query_tag_alter/
to my template file, how to do that?

Comment: another link about my issue. however it was implemented on module. can i implement it on template?
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45785/entityfieldquery-inner-join/54277#54277

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's usefull to use `db_select` for your case instead of `EntityFieldQuery()`. You cannot add `JOIN` directly to `EntityFieldQuery` because it's not supported, maybe in Drupal 8.

Your query can be rewritted with `db_select` like this :

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('nid'))
        ->leftJoin('field_data_field_show_on', 'fso', 'fso.entity_id = n.nid') // You can use INNER if you need
        ->leftJoin('field_data_field_perks_categories', 'fpc', 'fpc.entity_id = n.nid') // Same thing here
        ->leftJoin('field_data_field_perks_sub_categories', 'fpsc', 'fpsc.entity_id = n.nid') // And here also
        ->leftJoin('order', 'o', 'o.nid = n.nid') // Join artc_order
        ->condition('n.type', 'article', 'LIKE')
        ->condition('fso.field_show_on_tid', $group['identifier'])
        ->condition('fso.field_perks_categories_tid', $categories['tid'])
        ->condition('fso.field_perks_sub_categories_tid', $subcategory['tid'])
        ->condition('n.status', 1)
        ->orderBy('o.weight')
        ->execute();
```

PS: i can't test this query, because i don't have your database, but it's almost that.

PS2: Using queries into a **template.php** file is not a clean method, i know that in some extreme cases, we need to do this, but i think that Drupal has lot of hooks that allow us to what we need in our custom modules instead of **template.php** directly (it's only my opinion, i can be wrong)

Comment: thanks, that's very helpful. i use more like your query and it's work